# How to show supermarketapi products in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, multisite

I need to know if there is a better way of doing this than what I am thinking. http://www.supermarketapi.com/Methods_v1.aspx provides an API for US supermarket grocery retailers. I need to enable my site users to sell their chosen products using my site. For this can I use WP Multi-site? My users will also need to use a different domains/subdomains and their own admin panel. What should be a realistic approach? Can woocommerce be populated with those products on a user to user basis?

Comment: AnY heLlp?? I really need to know.